# Lync 2013 SDK .NET Core compatibility

Tags: .net-core, lync-client-sdk

Is the Lync 2013 SDK for desktop apps .NET Core compatible?
I couldn't find any documentation about this.

Answer (score 0):

The desktop SDK essentially hasn't changed since 2013 and predates .Net Core, it is best to stick with .net framework in this instance.

Comment: Is there a newer version of the SDK with the same functionalities?

Comment: Not that I have ever seen, however the Lync 2013 SDK is compatible with the newer Skype for Business desktop clients.